# Is there a way to deny access from internet to a domain apart to specific APIs?

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, arr

I have a domain e.g. *https://example.com* and I need to deny connections from browsers outside of the network except to some apis like *https://example.com/tablet/service/xxx* where `xxx` might be `login/app` or `access/data/user`. Those APIs are calling from a tablet application and we need them. But the access from the browser must my denied.

I tried `reverse proxy` through URL rewriting in and ARR IIS but I can't deny any other API. Can anyone help me? My app is running in ports 443 (external) and 8443 (internal). The dns points from 443 to 8443.

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "but I can't deny any other API" is untrue. Add a condition to this rule to verify `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is the simplest approach. If you want more control then it can be a different question.

Comment: Running applications with different security requirements on the very same web server is a very bad idea. Please consider splitting the applications by security.